# Custom MSP for Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy, decentralized-identity

I'm trying to use DIDs/VCs from hyperledger Indy with Hyperledger Fabric. Simply I want to replace Fabric's certificate based identity/MSP with DIDs/VCs. However, as far as I understand this is not direct. The existing code based have lots of dependencies on Fabric-CA. Could someone help me to figure out potential starting points to do this customisation?

Answer (score 0):

you cant try to use this modified peen-node:

https://github.com/trustbloc/fabric-mod

https://github.com/trustbloc/trustbloc-did-method/blob/main/docs/spec/trustbloc-did-method.md

or read this research:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.03277.pdf

or check other did:methods that support HLF:

https://www.w3.org/TR/did-spec-registries/

or look to this project:

https://github.com/BLOCKOTUS/blockotus-organism

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only framework that can verify DID/VCs from Hyperldeger Indy is the Hyperledger Aries. There are several projects where people are trying to integrate either some of the Indy or Aries functionalities into Fabric in order to be able to issue and verify DID/VCs.
Take a look at the following projects in the "Hyperledger Mentorship Program" community:

- [Hyperledger Fabric - Hyperledger Aries Integration to support Fabric as Blockchain ledger](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/display/INTERN/Hyperledger+Fabric+-+Hyperledger+Aries+Integration+to+support+Fabric+as+Blockchain+ledger#app-switcher)
- Or an older project [Extending HL Fabric for connecting with HL Indy](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6426989).

However, the easiest way is to have two DLTs, one for DID/VCs issue and verification (Indy), and one for transactions, etc.